# Postgresql Auto Update Column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, psql

For example, if  I have a table with structure like this:

| id | card_number | status | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | registered | 2024-07-10 15:00:00.000 | 2024-07-10 15:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 456 | approved | 2020-04-01 15:00:00.000 | 2020-04-01 15:00:00.000 |

When a user update its card status to `approved`, I want in exactly 1 days (24 hours) after that, the status automatically changed to `activated`. Is there any way I can do this natively with SQL query or do I need some PostgreSQL extension?

Comment: No, this is not natively supported. You could install pg_cron or so. And do you want to update the existing record or to insert a new record with the new status?

Comment: @FrankHeikens update existing record

Comment: When it's an automated proces, why do you even care? If all records will be activated 24 hours after now, store that date and this status immediately. That makes your code simpler and no need for a cron job

Answer (score 1):

There are no timeout triggered activities in PostgreSQL, but the canonical relational database solution to that problem is a different one anyway: define a view with a column `status` defined like

```
CASE WHEN status = 'approved' AND
          updated_at < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '24:00:00'
     THEN 'activated'
     ELSE status
END
```

Alternatively, build that expression into your query.